# References showing question marks

Tags: bibtex, lyx

In LyX, I'm using the reference style apsrev.bst, which I downloaded from here:

http://www.maik.ru/pub/tex/revtex4/

This reference style is the one used in Physical Review.

But now when I add references, they show up as question marks in brackets (?).

Why does this happen? how can I fix it?

Thank you for any efforts

Comment: Have you compiled your document more than once?

Comment: @CountZero LyX should take care of all the necessary runs automatically.

Comment: Yes, I compile it all the time... but I think Torbjorn has a point.

Comment: I think we need some more information to find the cause of the problem, it works for me.
To add the bibliography I used *Insert --> List/TOC --> BibTeX bibliography*.
The `apsrev` style is part of TeX Liveit seems, as I could choose it in the bibliography window without downloading. 
I then used one of the `.bib` files already listed in LyX (`xampl.bib`) and added a couple citations (*Insert --> Citation*) from it to the document.
After compiling with Ctrl + R everything shows up fine.

Comment: That's weird... could you please try it with document class "report"?

Comment: Works fine also with `report`. (For reference, this is Ubuntu with TeX Live 2011 and LyX 2.0.2.)

Comment: And by the way, you should add "@<username>" when replying to a person, that way they get notified, as you probably are of this comment. The site has Tab-completion of usernames, so if you write *@Torb* you'll get a box with my username, and you can hit the tab-key to finish it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. OK, it's still not working for me... I have no idea why. I'm using Windows 7 with the latest version of LyX and MiKTeX... is there anything you think I should check? Thank you

Comment: Does it work with other bibliography styles? Other bib-files? Can you see if Bibtex is run when you hit Ctrl + R (look closely in the status bar at the bottom of the window). It will only run, I think, if you've added a new citation. Perhaps reconfiguring LyX (Tools --> Reconfigure). And by the way, Revtex 4-1 is included in MikTeX as well, so you could have installed it with the MikTeX Package manager.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It works with some other styles. But they show the Author's name and the year of publication, and not the number of the reference. And I need to show the number of the reference, you know, article-style. Many styles show also the (?) instead of the number of the reference.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It has finally worked! I installed a gazillion packages from MikTeX package manager, and removed the harvard package, and from the bibliography options in Document Settings I enabled bibtex8... and it went OK. Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: Good to hear you worked it out!